# Recoverable fatal error when trying to run hook_query_TAG_alter()

Tags: 8, database

I used the approach provided [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1095656#comment-9778205) to reverse comments order in Drupal 8:

```
    /** Implements hook_query_TAG_alter().
 *
 * Alter comments query to order by DESC as well as the default ASC.
 */
function MYMODULENAME_query_comment_filter_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $orderby = &$query->getOrderBy();

  // Sorting for threaded comments.
  if (isset($orderby['torder'])) {
    // Sort by root parent first, then normal threaded.
    $query->addExpression("SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.thread, '.', 1)", 'rparent');
    $orderby = array('rparent' => 'DESC') + $orderby;
  }
  // Sorting for flat comments.
  else if (isset($orderby['c.cid'])) {
    $direction = 'DESC';

    $orderby['c.cid'] = $direction;
    $orderby = array('c.created' => $direction) + $orderby;
  }
}
```

but I receive the followig error when run the module:

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   mymd_query_comment_filter_alter() must be an instance of
>   QueryAlterableInterface, instance of
>   Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender given, called in
>   D:\wamp95\www\drupal83\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler.php
>   on line 501 and defined in mymd_query_comment_filter_alter()

what is the problem and how should I solve it?

Comment: I think I should use: Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query as argument.

Answer (score 1):

I used Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query as argument.

It solved the problem.

Comment: Yes see the docs. It should be AlterableInterface. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/8.2.x

Comment: Yes, you need to use "AlterableInterface" instead of "QueryAlterableInterface".   

`use Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface;
function MYMODULENAME_query_comment_filter_alter(AlterableInterface$query) {  
//.....
}`